# Not able to get read characteristic after write in BLE Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am working on a BLE device. 
- I am able to connect this device with app Using [BluetoothGATT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt)
- I am able to read all services, characteristic and advertiser data first time as soon as connect with BluetoothGatt.
- We have two characteristics one we need to read and another one for writing, I am able to write characteristic.

But The issue it I am not able to read characteristic after write.
As per my understanding

```
        @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                        BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)
```

or

```
        @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                     int status)
```

Should automatically called, these are Callback method of

My Characteristic Write code is

```
boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, state);
```

I am also enabling notification by below code

```
        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);
```

**I am stuck on Reading characteristics part after writing**

Any help appreciatable, Thank In Advance dear, I am stuck for 3 days on this point.

Answer (score 2):

onCharacteristicRead() and onCharacteristicChanged() are **not** automatically called.

onCharacteristicRead is triggered when you call characteristic.getValue().
Something like this:

```
BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac = ... ;
byte[] messageBytes = charac.getValue();
```

Where *charac* holds the characteristic you're trying to read and *messageBytes* holds the value read from the characteristic.

onCharacteristicChanged is called once you enable notifications. Looks like you're not enabling notifications completely.

```
public static String CLIENT_CONFIGURATION_DESCRIPTOR_STRING = "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";

...

            mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);

            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(
                    UUID.fromString(CLIENT_CONFIGURATION_DESCRIPTOR_STRING));
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            mBluetoothgatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

You need to add a writeDescriptor call to successfully enable notifications.